# fonts and xmls not found in Xcode's open framework built product

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

I want to move my open frameworks project to other machines for testing. but when I try to open a build product (exported via the organizer) the app starts up without the text I set (via ofTrueTypeFont). It also won't load any data from the xmls I use. This also happens if I open the exported product on the same machine.

fonts are loaded like:
in .h

```
ofTrueTypeFont fontLarge;
```

in .cpp

```
fontLarge.loadFont("font.ttf", 35);
fontLarge.drawString("Display that String", 30,30);
```

I have tried various build phases. copied the .ttfs and .xmls to various directories but the app won't find it.

tried a (/bin)data folder within /App/Contents, /Frameworks, /usr/... every folder that i could imagine in the final product. What am I missing here?

Xcode 4.6 / OS X 10.8.2 / OpenFrameworks 0073

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the best approach but this is how I solved it:

Add to your application setup:

```
ofSetDataPathRoot("../Resources/data/");
```

Then add a Copy Files Build Phase to your Target and set the Destination to "Resources" and Subpath to "data". From now on you may drag and drop the files you need into the Build Phase and they will be included.